# Access Salesforce Data from anonymous Javascript block from a third party application(not Salesforce)

Tags: javascript, access

Is it possible to access Salesforce records from an anonymous javascript block embedded in any third party application(not salesforce)?

Comment: yes you can access that using rest API implementation.

Comment: or use jsforce http://jsforce.github.io/ ..easy to use and you will get so many functionality

Comment: Hi Himanshu/Ratan , I am quite a beginner in javascript. If you can please share some step by step document, that will be very nice. I mean i have no idea how to use jsforce. A brief guidance/overview will be very helpful, so that i can start and explore.

Comment: @ Ratan , Thanks for the response.
I am quite a beginner in javascript.
I just have a javascript block on 3rd party app without any server side access and i need to access salesforce field infromation from there.
Can you please guide what are the pre-requisites and how to use JSforce since this is my first time?
It will be very kind of you if you can spare some moments for me.
Else if you have used JSForce in past, can you share the code/document?

Comment: @Himanshu , Thanks for the response.
I am quite a beginner in javascript.
I just have a javascript block on 3rd party app without any server side access and i need to access salesforce field information from there.
Can you please guide what are the pre-requisites and how to use JSforce since this is my first time?
It will be very kind of you if you can spare some moments for me.
Else if you have used JSForce in past, can you share the code/document?